# Custom cron not working in magento 2.2.6

Tags: module, magento2.2.6, magento-cron

I Have created the custom cron in my custom module. `crontab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
<job name="samplecron" instance="Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron\Run" method="execute">
<schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
</job>
</group>
</config>
```

Then `run.php`

```
<?php
namespace Learning\GreetingMessage\Cron;
class Run
{
   protected $_logger;
   protected $_oredrcontroller;

   public function __construct(
       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Learning\GreetingMessage\Controller\Index\Test $ordercontroller
   ) 
    {
     $this->_logger = $logger;
     $this->_oredrcontroller = $ordercontroller;
    }

   public function execute()
   {
       $this->_oredrcontroller->execute();
       $this->_logger->debug('Cron run successfully');
       return $this;
   }
}
```

I execute following commands in terminal

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod -R 777  .
php bin/magento cron:run
```

But my cron not working. In the function contorller `\Learning\GreetingMessage\Controller\Index\Test` execute . I wrote code to update values in my table. Nothing happens

Comment: Is the record falling in the cron_schedule table ?

Comment: @sourabh No i am not find any record with name "samplecron" in cron_schedule table

Comment: Did you check your var/log folder and if there is any error ?

Comment: @sourabh In system.log i found "Cron Job samplecron is missed at 2018-11-22 08:08:00 [] []"

Answer (score 0):

Since your comment states that your error says that it is missing executing the cron I can suggest you the below step:

Go to `Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Cron (Scheduled Tasks) -> Cron configuration options for group: index` you will get a setting called **Missed if Not Run Within**  by default the value is 15 minutes, you can change it as per your requirement.

Comment: i am not able to find the menu configuration in system

Comment: Edited the answer, you will find that option under store.

Comment: i did , still now i got main.INFO: Cron Job samplecron is missed at 2018-11-22 08:25:00 [] []